# How to annotate a Kubernetes Secret via the string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I've created a secret okay by doing this...`kubectl create secret generic <namespace> <secret-name>   --from-literal=value1=xxxx --from-literal=value2=xxxx --from-literal=value3=xxxx`

When I do a get command I get

```
    apiVersion: v1
    data:
    value1: xxxx
    value2: xxxx 
    value3: xxxx
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
    creationTimestamp: <time>
    name: <secret-name>
    namespace: <namespace>
    resourceVersion: <version number>
    uid: <alpha-numeric>
    type: Opaque
```

...the thing is...I was expecting to automatically include an annotations section below where it says metadata so that it should looks more like

```
    apiVersion: v1
    data:
    value1: xxxx
    value2: xxxx 
    value3: xxxx
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      annotations:
       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
       {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"value1":<value1>,"value2":<value2> ,"value3" <value3>},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"<secret-name>","namespace":" 
      <namespace>"},"type":"Opaque"}
    creationTimestamp: <time>
    name: <secret-name>
    namespace: <namespace>
    resourceVersion: <version number>
    uid: <alpha-numeric>
    type: Opaque
```

Is this ONLY possible if you add the secret from a file or is there away you can add this annotation information via the string literal..I've been searching the internet but the only solution I can find is via a file...not through a string as such....can anybody help?

Comment: ......or does it only add this bit when it gets actually applied?

Comment: `kubectl create` does not add a `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration`. You will only get that when you use `kubectl apply`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this ONLY possible if you add the secret from a file

yes, this is used to compare the live manifest and manifest in the file.
**But we annotate the secret even if it's created without a manifest file.**

> The kubectl apply command writes the contents of the configuration file to the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation. This is used to identify fields that have been removed from the configuration file and need to be cleared from the live configuration.

[merge-patch-calculation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#merge-patch-calculation)

so for example if we created secrets like

```
 kubectl create secret generic test  --from-literal=value1=xxxx
```

and now we want to patch this secrets with manifest file, we will get a warning `"Warning: resource secrets/test is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  value1: eHh4eA==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: playground-account-app
type: Opaque
```

and if we tried to apply this we will get warning

```
Warning: resource secrets/test is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
```

**Avoid these warning**:

The above warning is because of missing the annotation but we can annotate the object in the Kubernetes to fix and avoid these warning

[kubernetes-annotations](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/20/annotating-k8s-for-humans/#kubernetes-annotations)

```
 kubectl annotate secret test --overwrite  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration='{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"value1":"eHh4eA=="},"kind":"Secret","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"test","namespace":"namespace-name"},"type":"Opaque"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there away you can add this annotation information

Try append `--save-config` to the command:

kubectl create secret generic    --from-literal=value1=xxxx ... `--save-config`